# can't locate node [turtle_teleop_joy] in package [learning_joy]

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-hydro, joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using Hydro on Precise. Following the tutorials on joystick operation [here](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/ConfiguringALinuxJoystick) and [here](http://wiki.ros.org/joy/Tutorials/WritingTeleopNode). The joystick works, roscore is running, joy_node is running, when I do rostopic echo joy I see the vectors change as I expect when the joystick controls are moved. When I run roslaunch learning_joy turtle_joy.launch however, the joystick still works, topic echo shows still sending, but no movement of the turtle.

I'm still on the steep part of the learning curve so I could be wrong, but might this be a path problem? I've changed the launch file as suggested [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/172503/cannot-locate-node-joy/) (joy to joy_node) and also changed the last line from turtle_teleop to learning_joy (missed that bit on the tutorial) but still not getting it right. here's my screenshot:

```
roslaunch learning_joy turtle_joy.launch ... logging to /home/richard/.ros/log/68d0ca94-ef06-11e3-912a-00215c98e435/roslaunch-inga-7554.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile. 
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt 
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
    
    started roslaunch server http://inga:32850/
    
    SUMMARY
    PARAMETERS * /axis_angular * /axis_linear * /rosdistro * /rosversion * /scale_angular * /scale_linear * /turtle_joy/deadzone * /turtle_joy/dev
    
    NODES / sim (turtlesim/turtlesim_node) teleop (learning_joy/turtle_teleop_joy) turtle_joy (joy/joy_node)
    
    ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
    
    core service [/rosout] found process[sim-1]: started with pid [7572] process[turtle_joy-2]: started with pid [7596] ERROR: cannot launch node of type [learning_joy/turtle_teleop_joy]: can't locate node [turtle_teleop_joy] in package [learning_joy]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173089/can%27t-locate-node-%5Bturtle_teleop_joy%5D-in-package-%5Blearning_joy%5D/) by [richkappler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2694/richkappler/) on ROS Answers with karma: 106 on 2014-06-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alex Ortega](https://answers.ros.org/users/23244/alex-ortega/) on 2015-07-18**:
I have the same problem. Have you found the solution to your problem? Help, please!

**Comment by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) on 2015-07-19**:
Please do not use Answer form to ask questions, use comments or create your own question instead. ROS Answers is not a forum, but Q&A site.

**Comment by [Abdul Mannan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25557/abdul-mannan/) on 2016-01-12**:
I have followed the very same example from the book "Learning ROS for Robotics Programming second edition on Jade on ubuntu 15.04. I am also having the similar problem. Someone please sort it out. Thanks.

**Comment by [Suneet](https://answers.ros.org/users/31613/suneet/) on 2017-09-03**:
I also had the same issue .I solved it  . After adding the the following lines(given below) in CMakeLists.txt . In the terminal  I wrote :
$ cd catkin_ws 
$ catkin_make

"add_executable(turtle_teleop_joy src/turtle_teleop_joy.cpp)

target_link_libraries(turtle_teleop_joy ${catkin_LIBRARIES})"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The line from original tutorial launch-file (on the second link you gave)

```
<node pkg="turtle_teleop" type="turtle_teleop_joy" name="teleop"/>
```

tells `roslaunch` to start a node by running `turtle_teleop_joy` executable (`type` parameter) which is located within `turtle_teleop` package (`pkg` parameter). If you change `pkg` parameter on this line `roslaunch` will search for the executable within another package/folder, i.e. `learning_joy`. So, if there is no such executable (node) there, then roslaunch will issue an error.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2015-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1